# What does this roman numeral (2) mean?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, classical-music

[image: Roman numeral on image]

as you can see above, there is a II in two places, what does that mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is trying to indicate that the following two bars is played in the second position. (fret 2 to 5)